# Error in Report Builder 3.0

Tags: vba, reporting-services

I have a text box named txtError on a report that I want to toggle betweem hidden and visible based on a parameter using this code:

```
Public Sub ShowHideUrl(ByVal param As String)
    If Trim(param) = ""
        txtError.Hidden = False
    Else
        txtError.Hidden = True
    End If 
End Sub
```

I keep getting:

There is an error on line 2 of custom code: 'txtError' is not declared.  It may be anaccessible due to its protection level.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Donald

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be necessary to use VBA for this, SSRS text boxes have a Visibility.Hidden property. You can set this up like so.

```
=IIf(Trim(Parameters!yourParameter.Value) == "", True, False)
```

Comment: Thanks that is helping because I can turn the text box on but what I am I trying to is to display an error message if somebody does not have access to a report so they can request access.  Right now if the user does not have access they just get an standard error but I want to redirect to a page where they can request access.

Comment: Nice idea Donald, but you're out of luck. If the user doesn't have permission to view the report then they will, as you have discovered, just get the standard access denied page. Even if you could put logic in the report to handle this, it'll never execute because the report hasn't been opened.

Comment: Thank you so much for verifying what I thought was true.  I will let my boss know that we cannot do it.  Have a nice day.